# Pygame error loading a sound: Module format not recognised

Tags: python, pygame

I've been having problems trying to load and play sounds in pygame. Most people seem to have trouble with MP3s but for some reason, I can't even get wavs to play.

```
>>> f=open('menuscreen.wav',"rb")
>>> pygame.mixer.init()
>>> pygame.mixer.music.load(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
pygame.error: Module format not recognized
```

and neither does this work:

```
>>> k = pygame.mixer.Sound('menuscreen.wav')
>>> pygame.mixer.init()
>>> pygame.mixer.music.load(k)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
pygame.error: Couldn't read from RWops
```

and neither does this:

```
>>> import pygame
>>> pygame.mixer.init()
>>> pygame.mixer.music.load('menuscreen.wav')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
pygame.error: Unable to load WAV file
```

I'm using 2.7.2 and pygame 1.9.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should load the file by passing the file name as first argument. This works on my system (same python and pygame versions) just fine:

```
>>> import pygame
>>> pygame.mixer.init()
>>> pygame.mixer.music.load('filename.wav')
>>> pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

HTH!

Comment: @JJJ The most obvious explanation is that there is something wrong with your sound file then. Maybe it's not in the directory you believe it is? (Try to pass the absolute path to it rather than the fname only). Has the file the wrong permissions? Are you sure the file is a real wav and not - for example - an MP4 mistakenly given the extension `.wav`? Can you play the file in an external wav player? I'm on ubuntu 64 bit, but this should not really make a difference...

Comment: Ah, thanks alot. I found the problem. The WAV was, like you said, not a WAV at all, but an MP3.

Comment: @JJJ Then you should select the answer as accepted, if it solved your issue! :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid writing every line of code `pygame.mixer`
you can also do:

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('songX.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
```

(as a shorter version of @Mac's answer)